# How can I stop "AAM Update Notifier" from automatically starting?

Tags: macos

I’ve just found the name of a process that can't be removed from my menu bar in OS X.

Its name is "AAM Update Notifier" and I was able to quit it using Activity Monitor. How can I make sure it doesn’t start again next time I restart my computer?

Comment: Don't just "edit" your question, as it will be read for all eternity. Completely exchange its contents so everyone knows what exactly you want to know.

Comment: Well I tried to make it more specific – is that okay, Ollie? Also, I think the program you meant is called "AAM" notifier, not "AAC".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it's not in *System Preferences → Accounts → Login items*, there's probably a Launch Agent set up for it.

There are two ways to deal with this problem.

#### 1. Delete the Launch Agent entries

According to this [process information](http://www.macinside.info/process.php?id=1087), you should delete the following file(s):

- `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist`
- `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist`

You could also edit them:

- Where `<key>RunAtLoad</key>` is `<true/>`, change it to `<false/>`.

#### 2. Disable the update process

[This article](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/21/stop-adobe-update-manager-launching/) suggests to run the following command:

```
defaults write com.adobe.AdobeUpdater.Admin Disable.Update -bool yes
```

You should maybe log out and log in again.

Comment: I checked Login Items. I’ll try these other things now.

Comment: OK I edited /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist where it had <key>RunAtLoad</key><true/> I changed it to <false/>, logged out, and back in, and it appears to have worked! Thanks :)

Comment: I deleted both launch agent files, but did a `$ launchctl remove com.adobe.AAM.Scheduler-1.0` instead of step 2

Answer (score 3):

Adobe's website has [instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/disable-auto-updates-application-manager.html) for turning off AAM (for Creative Suite 5 "CS5") that are different than the techniques described above. 
Adobe's technique involves putting a small text file with some given text at special places.

For computer-wide blocking, put the text at

***[startup disk]***/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AAMUpdaterInventory/1.0/AdobeUpdaterAdminPrefs.dat

Or for user-account blocking, put the text at

/Users/***[username]***/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AAMUpdater/1.0/AdobeUpdaterPrefs.dat

See the adobe page (linked above) for the text that goes in the file: it differs depending whether you're doing this before or after installing CS5.